# Page Navigation Won't Stay On One Line

Tags: html, css

Here is my html:

```
<div id="leftmenu">
    <ul>
      <li class="border"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li class="border"><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
      <li class="border"><a href="ourwork.html">Our Work</a></li>
      <li class="border"><a href="testimonials.html">Testimonials</a></li>
      <li class="border"><a href="clients.html">Clients</a></li>
      <li class="border"><a href="quote.html">Get a Quote</a></li>
      <li class="border"><a href="documents.html">Documents &amp; Forms</a></li>
      <li class="border"><a href="charities.html">Charity Information</a></li>
      <li class="border"><a href="jobs.html">Need a Job or Gig?</a></li>
      <li class="border"><a href="casting.html">Casting Calls</a></li>
      <li><a href="ourteam.html">Our Team</a></li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
#leftmenu {
    position:relative;
    min-width:100%;
    background-color:white;
    border-top:1px solid gray;
}

#leftmenu ul li{
    float:left;
    padding:7px;
    font-family:Georgia;
    font-size:small;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
```

What I am looking to do is have the nav bar resize to fit the parent element it is in. I also want it to resize depending on screen size as well. I have tested this on my dell 15 inch laptop screen and then tested it on my Mac 26 inch screen and the nav bar doesn't extend all the way to the end of the centered div on the Mac screen but does on the Dell screen. If I get it to extend on the Mac screen, it overflows on the smaller Dell screen. Do I just have to deal with the short nav bar on the Mac screen in order to get it to work on smaller screens?

Comment: What I usually do is make the LIs display:inline; and make the UL text-align:center; and let it wrap if necessary.  Let me work up an idea and I'll post it in a few.

Answer (score 0):

You can use display:table; et al, to make it fit how you need it to fit.  I also moved the border switch to the last list item so that you don't have to use so many classes.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <style type="text/css">
        #leftmenu { display: table; width: 100%; }
        ul { display: table-row; }
        li { border-right: solid 1px #f08; display: table-cell; height: 3em; }
        li.noBorder { border: none; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="leftmenu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="ourwork.html">Our Work</a></li>
            <li><a href="testimonials.html">Testimonials</a></li>
            <li><a href="clients.html">Clients</a></li>
            <li><a href="quote.html">Get a Quote</a></li>
            <li><a href="documents.html">Documents &amp; Forms</a></li>
            <li><a href="charities.html">Charity Information</a></li>
            <li><a href="jobs.html">Need a Job or Gig?</a></li>
            <li><a href="casting.html">Casting Calls</a></li>
            <li class="noBorder"><a href="ourteam.html">Our Team</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Just make sure there is enough horizontal room for it because you know how tables spill over their containers when necessary.

Or as mentioned above use display:inline; on the LI and let it wrap.